# Gradle build error using react native

Tags: node.js, react-native, android-gradle-plugin

I get this error when trying to run an app on an android emulator(Android Studio) from a console window:

$ react-native run-android
Scanning folders for symlinks in C:\Users\Brian\desktop\codervets\arrive-alive\aa_app\node_modules (27726ms)
Starting JS server...
Building and installing the app on the device (cd android && gradlew.bat installDebug)...
Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)
Configuration 'compile' in project ':app' is deprecated. Use 'implementation' instead.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.

  > The SDK directory 'c:\Users\eelia001\AppData\local\android\sdk1' does not exist.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 4m 51s
Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
set up your Android development environment:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/android-setup.html

And yet my sdk directory in android studio has the following directory:
C:\Users\Brian\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk

Has anyone else ran into this issue? If so, how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The error states:

> The SDK directory 'c:\Users\eelia001\AppData\local\android\sdk1' does not exist.

And you say your SDK is in:

> C:\Users\Brian\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk

Since those aren't the same directory, my guess is that's the problem. Are you perhaps logged in as the wrong user? You're going to want to check that `ANDROID_HOME` is set correctly.

Comment: how do I set android home?

Comment: btw, I'm the only user

Comment: That documentation page doesn't exist anymore (from your build failed error), which makes me think perhaps you have quite an old RN version. Is this a project started from scratch, or downloaded from somewhere? If you don't recognise the `eelia001` user, you might want to start looking around your project for that string. Sometimes there's a `local.properties` file in the `android` directory under the RN project's root directory.

Comment: [This](https://shift.infinite.red/getting-started-with-react-native-development-on-windows-90d85a72ae65) looks like a reasonable tutorial for RN on Windows, including setting up the Android environment.

Answer (score 0):

So I'm not sure why it was setup the way it was, but the way to fix it is to go to Advanced System Settings → Environment variables. Thank you to @Rich Churcher for the link to a proper tutorial (it's outdated but the steps worked).